# Gradle shortcut notations does not work for copy task

Tags: gradle

I'm new to gradle and i tried to copy files from one folder to another using a task of "Copy" type, but it does not work. The following is my script:

```
def dest = 'newfolder'
task copy(type: Copy) << {
    println dest
    from "src"
    into dest
}
```

But if i remove the "<<" and run **gradle copy** again, it works. Script like following:

```
def dest = 'newfolder'
task copy(type: Copy) {
    println dest
    from "src"
    into dest
}
```

Why doesn't it work if i use "<<" ?

But when i run another following scripts, they all work.

```
task hello << {
    println 'Hello world!'
}
task hello {
    println 'Hello world!'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<<` (short for `doLast`) adds a task action, which will be executed after the `Copy` task's main task action (which does the copying). At that point it's too late to configure the task, as the main action has already completed.